# how to change the navigation drawer theme with backward compatibility

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my application i have to change the navigation drawer same as Action bar's which is light now How i can change the navigation drawer **theme** to light by default it is dark?? I search for this but didn't find anything satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change background color of your list view or change theme of your list-view raw theme